# Miscellaneous notification not enabling from settings

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a push notification demo which is working fine. But there's an issue while enabling the notification alert from settings.

I have send a notification from firebase cloud messaging console and the notification is received as expected and now when I long click on that notification and disable it the notification's are not coming still expected behaviour see **(Image Left)**. 
But when I try to enable this miscellaneous notification from settings as see **(Image Right)** and then go back and again try to enable it doesn't allow me to enable it. It is always getting disabled itself. So what should I do to enable it again.

[image: Image 1]      [image: Image 2]

Also when I enable it the marked area options are still disabled and after going back and again try to enable it doesn't allow me to enable it. It is always getting disabled itself.

[image: Image 3]

Below is my code for the push notification

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                            return;
                        }

                        // Get new Instance ID token
                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();

                        // Log and toast
                        Log.d(TAG, "Token : " + token);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.e("onMessageReceived","notification : "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using Oreo 8.1

Comment: see my updated answer